# How to use CI trigger to run a build of a branch other than master when pushing changes to another repo in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two Repos, `Repo A` (with YAML `Pipeline A`) and `Repo B` (dependency of `Repo A` as well as a stand-alone product) both in the same project in Azure DevOps. Now I want to run `Pipeline A` with any changes from both repos. Therefore I used [Multi-repo triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops#multi-repo-triggers), but this only works on the master branch of `Repo A`.

We have multiple release branches in both repos and I want to configure the pipeline to run a build of the release branch of `Repo A` whenever there are changes in the corresponding Release branch of `Repo B`. I also want to run the pipeline whenever there are changes in the master branches.

I have tried to add this to the master branch of `Repo A`:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master_A
    trigger:
     branches:
       include:
         - refs/heads/master_A
  - repository: Repo B
    type: git
    name: Repo B
    ref: refs/heads/master_B
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
         - refs/heads/master_B
```

and this to the Release branch of `Repo A`:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/Release-A
    trigger:
     branches:
       include:
         - refs/heads/Release-A
  - repository: Repo B
    type: git
    name: Repo B
    ref: refs/heads/Release-B
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
         - refs/heads/Release-B
```

But that way, it only runs when there are changes in `master_A`, `Release-A` or `master_B` but it does not run when there are changes in `Release-B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your YAML sample, I can reproduce the same situation. It only runs when there are changes in master_A, Release-A or master_B but it does not run when there are changes in Release-B.

[image]

This is an expected behavior.

Refer to this doc: [Mutiple Repo Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers)

> When a pipeline is triggered, Azure Pipelines has to determine the version of the YAML file that should be used and a version for each repository that should be checked out. If a change to the self repository triggers a pipeline, then the commit that triggered the pipeline is used to determine the version of the YAML file. If a change to any other repository resource triggers the pipeline, then the latest version of YAML from the default branch of self repository is used.

If it is a commit to the self repository, it will trigger the pipeline based on the YAML file corresponding to the submission confirmation. So the master_A, Release-A can trigger the Pipeline.

But for the resource repo, it determines the YAML version to use based on the Self Repo's **Default branch**. Therefore it will trigger the pipeline based on the Repo resource branch(master_B) set in master_A.

You can navigate to **Azure Repo -> Branches** to check the Default Branch.

[image]

If you need to use Release_B branch to trigger the Pipeline, you need to change the Default Branch to Release_A.

Here is a summary:

When you set the Default Branch to master_A, the following branches can trigger the pipeline.

```
master_A Release-A master_B
```

When you set the Default Branch to Release_A, the following branches can trigger the pipeline.

```
master_A Release-A Release-B
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have overlooked that last sentence in the documentation. Then it´s just not possible to achieve this...